# Output won't print for some reason

Tags: java, loops, printing, println

I've been working on a program that is supposed to output the winning status of a racing cart.  I thought I had everything set up correctly, and followed my instructor's outline in class last week.  However, in doing so I cannot get the output to print.  My thought is that I may be stuck in a loop, but I don't really know how to get out of it.  I've been working on it for four hours now, and have searched for answers low and high to no avail. I get no errors when compiling, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Assignment2{

public static void main(String args[]){

}

int r, cart, value;

public void race(){ //generates random number to assign value to cart
    Random ran = new Random();
    int r = ran.nextInt(0) + 6;
            value = r;
    }
public int getValue(){ //assigns value to carts
    return value;
    }
public void display(){ //sys.out to print results
    race();

    if (value == 5){
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("|____|  Winning Status = 5");
        System.out.println(" o o");
        }
    else if(value == 4){
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("|____|  Winning Status = 4");
        System.out.println(" o o");
        }
    else if(value == 3){
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("|____|  Winning Status = 3");
        System.out.println(" o o");
        }
    else if(value == 2){
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("|____|  Winning Status = 2");
        System.out.println(" o o");
        }
    else if(value == 1){
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("|____|  Winning Status = 1");
        System.out.println(" o o  YOU'RE FIRST! CONGRATS!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that value = r.  Even adding that in, nothing changes.

Comment: can you edit the question and add `value = r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your `main()` method, so nothing is actually executed. Perhaps you mean:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    (new Assignment2()).display();
}
```

As your code exists now, you should do away with `r` (it is unused) and change the following:

```
// int r = ran.nextInt(0) + 6;
value = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I kept trying to run display in main as just display();, but it kept stating that I couldn't call a non-static into a static, even with changing the methods all to static.  I couldn't remember how to call the methods into the main, even though I had done it below, haha - this makes a lot of sense now.  Thank you so much.  I'm pretty new to programming, so every bit of help and all the reminders I get helps very much.

Comment: Will it really work? ran.nextInt(0) will surely through an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: No, it didn't work.  When I changed it to ran.nextInt(5)+1; it ran once, and now it won't print again.  :/  I'm not sure why...

Comment: @chopin.kochanek it only runs once because you only call `display()` once.. you'll have to call it in a loop to run multiple times

Comment: @KuldeepJain thanks, didn't notice that one but someone pointed it out in another answer

Comment: @paislee I only want it to print once when the program is ran, but when I compile and run again, it won't print.  Even with exiting and restarting jGrasp, it won't print again.  Do I still need to make a loop?

Comment: @paislee, nevermind, I figured it out.  I had to put back in the r = value for some reason.  When I did that, it worked perfectly.  For some reason, the random number = value just wasn't cutting it.  :D  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @chopin.kochanek No problem. we can't help you debug your homework here, but we _can_ answer specific programming questions. If you have more trouble, try fiddling with it yourself for a while, and if you can formulate a good question, come back and post a new question.

Comment: That's the part I appreciate the most, the specifics!  Sometimes I just need to see things in a different way.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

`int r = ran.nextInt(0) + 6;` and `value = r` would mean that `value` is at least 6. Thus you don't meet any condition. Try `if (value >= 5)` and you should see the corresponding message.

Yet better, try `int r = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;` to get values between 1 and 5.

Comment: Thanks :)  That makes a lot more sense than ran.nextInt(0) + 6;  My instructor had it typed on the board exactly like that, so I just followed her lead.  Glad to see when people lend me the right information to do a job, haha!  :)

Comment: So, when I changed it to ran.nextInt(5)+1; it ran and printed cart 5, but now it won't print again after subsequent runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method contains no code. That's why your program does nothing. Change it to:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Assignment2 as = new Assignment2();
    as.display();
}
```

Comment: You will get a compile error because `display()` is not in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you initialize r in `race()`´s local scope.

Answer (score 0):

A program starts its execution in the `main()` method so, if like in your example, you have no code in `main()` the program will finish that method and then terminate.

In you're program it looks like you're trying to use `display()`. To use this you first need an instance of your class Assignment2.

This creates an instance of the class Assignment2 called a2

```
Assignment2 a2 = new Assignment2();
```

You can then use your object that we named a2 to call any method. Here I'm calling `display()`

```
a2.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this `int r = ran.nextInt(n) + 6;` `n` has to be a positive number else you will get `IllegalArgumentException`, which in your case is 0.

As Thomos suggested you should use `value = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;` to get values between 1 and 5 and it will work fine. Follow the javadoc [Random.nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from that you have to do this chages as well

```
public static void race(){ //generates random number to assign value to cart
    Random ran = new Random();
    int r = ran.nextInt(5) + 1;
    value=r;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    display();
}
```

I swtiched all the methods to "static" ;